# android 3G permission

Tags: android

i wrote in the manifest file this permissions:

```
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

and when i start the app it wrote: "unfortanely the app stopped" and exit from it
in Logcat i saw the line that the program fail is:

```
Class conmanClass;
Field iConnectivityManagerField;
iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
```

what is the problem?can anyone help me to fix it?

this is the logcat:

```
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.voicerecognitiondemo/com.example.voicerecognitiondemo.VoiceRecognitionDemo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at com.example.voicerecognitiondemo.VoiceRecognitionDemo.onCreate(VoiceRecognitionDemo.java:55)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-14 09:11:49.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1669):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: i add the logcat to the original post

Comment: Post the code at VoiceRecognitionDemo.onCreate(VoiceRecognitionDemo.java:55) . you should probably check which variable is null on this line

Comment: the line 55 is:"   iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
" on oncreate function..i spent alot of hours inorder to slove the problem and didnt find it yet...i hope someone here will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forgot to initialize `Class conmanClass;` do it and try again
like this

`conmanClass=new Class();` //if you are using default constructor then else use the proper constroctor to initialize you `conmanClass`